# Finding Volume of Solid if Region is Base - Equilateral Triangles & Quarter Circles

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to find the volume of a solid if a region is the base of a 3D solid with cross sections perpendicular to the x axis. There are two ways I want to find this: once with equilateral triangles and again with quarter circles.

The good news is that I have my code set up with the two functions and the left and right endpoints (this is for x > 0).

From here, I'm a little confused as to how to get this to work. This is what I have so far on my equilateral triangle problem:

```
f[x_] := 3x^3 - 0.75x^5
g[x_] := x^2 - 6x + 2
{x1, x2}=x/. Solve[f[x]==g[x] && x > 0,x, Reals];
sideLength=Sqrt[3](f[x]-g[x])/2;
volumeTri=Integrate[1/4*Pi*sideLength^2, {x, x1, x2}]
```

This is what I have for the quarter circle one:

```
f[x_] := 3x^3 - 0.75x^5
g[x_] := x^2 - 6x + 2
{x1, x2}=x/. Solve[f[x]==g[x] && x > 0,x, Reals];
radius=(f[x]-g[x])/(2Pi);
volumeQC=Integrate[1/4*Pi*radius^2, {x, x1, x2}]
```

Both compile, but I'm getting answers that are far, far different. The triangle one returns 43.8402 and the quarter circle 1.48065.

I get a feeling I've got some really minor little error in here that is triggering this but I'm not that well-versed in Mathematica so I'm wondering what exactly is going on here.

Comment: Could you add a sketch of the geometric situation involved? I'm having trouble understanding your process.

Comment: I don't have a sketch and barely understand the situation myself here. Basically it's the area between the curve 3x^3 - 0.75x^5 and the curve x^2 - 6x + 2, bounded by x > 0...and we're supposed to visualize the volume with equilateral triangles.